# Visual Studio - plugin finding/removing dead code?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, plugins, add-in, dead-code

Anyone knows any **free** Visual Studio add-in that would find and/or delete dead (unused) code? I saw such possibility in MZ-Tools, but it's a little expensive as for private use ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends... For .NET you can use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) for finding usused  code and variables.

Comment: Hmm, but FxCop analyzes the managed code. I'm not sure if it would do the thing?

Comment: You get warnings like: CA1804: Remove unused locales; or CA1811: Avoid uncalled private code; So I would say that is something...

Answer (score 1):

You can also install ReSharper. It generally warns about unused variables and methods in a class file. You can see it as you are coding. It underlines it. It does seem to miss a couple but FxCop did seem to find the rest for me.

UPDATE: Sorry didn't see the FREE part. BUT after using ReSharper for a while it is definitely worth the money.

Comment: You can at least use it as trial version for some days. I tested it (but didn't buy) and also think that it's really good.

Comment: I've already heard many good things about Resharper, quite expensive unfortunately.